# Complex Function Notation (Pre-Calculus / Calc 1)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

The question is if $f(x) = 4(x^2) - 3x + 12$, find $\dfrac{f(x+2) - f(x)}2$.

I am having trouble with where to start on this problem, it is fairly complex compared to what I am used to such as you know if $f(x) = 3x^2$, find $(x - 5)$ you just substitute $x - 5$ for the $x$ in the main equation.

I just need some assistance on where to start with the substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $f(x)=4x^2-3x+12$. So

$$\begin{align}
f(x+2) &= 4(x+2)^2-3(x+2)+12 \\
 &= 4(x^2+4x+4)-3(x+2)+12 \\
 &= 4x^2+16x+16-3x-6+12 \\
 &= 4x^2+13x+22
\end{align}$$

Now substitute that and your formula for $f(x)$ into the expression $\dfrac{f(x+2)-f(x)}2$ to get what you want. Can you finish?

Comment: Yes if I calculate it would you be willing to check my answer for me?

Comment: @user2311215: Yes, if you put your answer here before I go to bed (in 38 minutes). Otherwise you will need to wait until tomorrow for my answer.

Comment: I ended up getting 5x + 17, is that correct?

Comment: @user2311215: No, that is not what I get. I just checked my answer graphically and it works, while yours does not.

Comment: I will put my steps here. I did (4(x^2) + 13x + 22) - (4(x^2) - 3x + 12) that comes out to (10x + 34)/2 which comes out to 5x + 17

Comment: sorry that was an accident enter press see previous comment

Comment: @user2311215: You did not distribute the minus sign in front of the parenthesis correctly. You don't get $13x-3x$ but rather $13x+3x$, and you don't get $22+12$ but rather $22-12$.

Comment: Thank you very much that was a poor mistake on my part

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{f(x+2)-f(x)}2$ = $(\dfrac{4x^2+13x+22-(4x^2-3x+12)}2)$

$(\dfrac{4x^2+13x+22-4x^2+3x-12}2)$

$(\dfrac{16x+10}2)$ = $8x + 5$